# VS2008 - error in deserialization from web service

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, web-services, soap

I have an error in deserialization from calling an operation in an external web service (https). The error is "Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'score'." Score is a credit score operation. The stack trace includes "There is an error in XML document (2, 157)." but I don't know how to get the XML document so I can identify the problem.

I am using Visual Studio 2008, and the service proxy is generated code. My question is: Can I get a dump of the response somehow? Tried Fiddler, but when using transport level security (https), the error changes to "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

Comment: So the error is being returned to you by the service? Sounds like you're sending bad XML. Run in debug and check your request.

Comment: Figured out that the response contained the xml prefix xsd for things such as strings etc. The namespace prefix definition is not included in the response from the server. The proxy then fails with a deserialization error. Haven't figured out the best way to deal with this yet, but that is another question entirely.

Comment: +1 BUT ... any chance of knowing how you fixed this? I am getting the same

Comment: @JohnIdol Forced the service provider to fix their service and include the namespace definition. This however took about 6 months to get done, and in-between I coded a wcf snip which added the namespace before deserialization (if it didn't exist).

The problem here is really Java VS MS web service interoperability. There are some assumptions on both sides that make deserialization difficult sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) may offer more details on the exception. Try setting the trace level to Error or Warning.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly and was easy to set up.